# Kubernetes RS controller - error looking up service account k8s-tiller/k8s-tiller: serviceaccount "k8s-tiller" not found

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm running into the following issue with tiller:

```
Type     Reason        Age                From                   Message
  ----     ------        ----               ----                   -------
  Warning  FailedCreate  18s (x15 over 1m)  replicaset-controller  Error creating: pods "tiller-deploy-6f65cf89f-" is forbidden: error looking up service account k8s-tiller/k8s-tiller: serviceaccount "k8s-tiller" not found
```

However a `k8s-tiller` service account exists (in the default namespace).

How can I investigate this further? Is it possibly looking in the `k8s-tiller` namespace, and if so could I just create the service account manually then?

Answer (score 2):

I faced issues with helm till below actions:

```
  curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get | bash
  kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller
  kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
  kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}' 
  helm init --service-account tiller / helm init --service-account tiller --upgrade(in case you have already done heln init)
```

Hope this help you.